# Show datatable in tabcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a datagridview . and tabcontrol. before i use this code to load datatable in newform with value selected. here is the code

```
private void dgvSatuan_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            dgvSatuan.ReadOnly = false;
            str = dgvSatuan.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            i = dgvSatuan.Rows[e.RowIndex].Index;

            fSatuan opSatuan = new fSatuan(str, i, ID);

            opSatuan.ShowDialog();

            showDataSatuan();


        }
```

how to load datatable when datagridview is selected and the value detail is show to textView in tabPage1?

[image: Images]

Comment: The answer to your question could be lengthy - you should look into data bindings and master-detail bindings. Google knows an abundance of pages providing samples on how to do master-detail-bindings in C#.

Comment: can you give me a sample code to binding datagridview to tab control? i try to search in google. but im cant understand. im newbie. @ThorstenDittmar

Comment: You don't want to bind to the tab control - you want to bind to the controls on the tab. I won't give you code. There's a lot of code on the internet for data binding master-detail. It won't help you to just use some code - you need to *understand* what's going on. So code I could give you would leave you as helpless as any code you find on the net. You need to create a data set which contains relations between the tables. Then you need to use `BindingSource`s to bind the data.